lexicographical sorting of ULIDs in R seems to not take into account milliseconds (using ulid package)
I would like to have ULIDs with a milliseconds timestamp. What am I getting wrong/missing?
As stated in the ulid package docs, the ULID specs include:


1.21e+24 unique ULIDs per millisecond
Lexicographically sortable!
Monotonic sort order (correctly detects and handles the same millisecond)


Sorting the ULIDs works when generating one ULID every second.
library(ulid)
library(stringi)

gen_ulid <- \(sleep) replicate(5, {Sys.sleep(sleep); generate()})

u <- gen_ulid(1)
stri_sort(u) == u

> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

However, when generating a ULID every 100ms, it does not.
u <- gen_ulid(.1)
stri_sort(u) == u

> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

Also, I noted that there are no milliseconds when converting the ULID timestamp to Posix:
df <- unmarshal(u)
format(df$ts, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")

[1] "2024-05-30 11:17:36.000" "2024-05-30 11:17:36.000" "2024-05-30 11:17:36.000"
[4] "2024-05-30 11:17:36.000" "2024-05-30 11:17:36.000"

Does the R implementation not work on the milliseconds level? What am I missing?

You're right, it appears the ULID doesn't store milliseconds, contrary to the docs.  The ULIDS I generated all start with "000", so I suspect the coding has a bug:  they forgot to multiply the timestamp by 1000 before converting to an integer value.
It's probably easy to fix.  You should submit a PR.
EDITED to add:  There's some discussion of this here:
https://github.com/eddelbuettel/ulid/issues/2
It appears to be a limitation of the upstream ulid library which was reported a few years ago. The submitted fix hasn't been dealt with.
2ND EDIT:  The R package now imports the submitted fix, so it should be fine as of version 0.3.1.2 (not on CRAN yet).
